# Modelling Complicated Rubik cube

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make my speed cube model again and this time make each piece more accurate. I made the 2 other pieces now I'm on the last piece. The center is shaped strangely. As you can see by my homemade wireframe, this is what I'm trying to make, but I need to know how to make this. I'm sure I'm complicating this, it appears to be just a box with a circle extended out and some bevels.

[image]
[image]

Thanks to https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots I was able to make it right.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a plane, bevel the vertices, use the *Operator* box to set the parameters:

[image]

Extrude up, then right click *LoopTools > Circle* for the top face:

[image]

Bevel the edges:

[image]

Inset the top face, here is what you get at the end:

[image]

Comment: OMG that's perfect! After following your steps, I had an issue with my final result. The 4 corners on the bottom did not look like yours after the bevel. It still had sharp corners at the verticals like your second image, but I think I got it. I had to tweak a few things. Thank you so much.